# apollo graphql server subscription - send only if data differs

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

So I created a subscription in apollo server.

i have my data for that request coming from multiple classes, nested in each other, and this works just fine.

But if I would like apollo to only send out the message if the values the client requested actually changed from the last update.

I can't just cache and compare the last sent object, as I don't know which fields this specific connection is interested in.

Is there a hook or something, that would let me compare the current "over the wire" message before it is sent, so I could compare it with the last "over the wire" message and decide if I actually want to send it?

Putting it in example let's say I have a data structure defined:

```
{
  foo: "valueA",
  bar: "valueB"
}
```

If I were to subscribe with one client to foo and another client to bar, and valueB got updatet to valueC, I would want only the client subscribed to bar to get an update, as the message for the client subscribed to foo would be the same as before.

While I could try to manually filter the data to recreate what would actually be sent to the specific client, this would be sort of redundant, as apollo already does this. Much rather I'd like to intercept the JSON message which gets sent over the websocket, compare it with a stored copy of the last message and decide whether I actually want to send it or to silently discard it.

Also I'm not sure how to find out, which fields the client subscribed to, but then again, I really don't want to go down that route recreating functionality apollo already has built in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in apollo graphql by any stretch of the imagination, but I had encountered some cases that could help you with this.
What I'd check first though, is wether Apollo server supports hot/cold subscriptions, but the truth is, that doesn't help much in a case of many connections.
What you should look into is a context of a connection. If it works as I think it works you should be able to create a custom resolver that'd do something along the lines of:

```js
export const SomeResolver = {
  Subscription: {
    subscribeToSomeMessages: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
        (rootValue, args, context, info) => {
          return pubsub.asyncIterator(["YOUR EVENT"])
        },
        (payload, variables, context, info) => {
          {here compare payload with context}
          {update context with new value}
          return {if values differ}
        }
      )
    },
...
```

You can then pass this resolver into ApolloServer initialisation block.
Hope that helps and gives you something to start with